# Swift: Declaring a delegate in Struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct, delegates

I want to declare a delegate in Swift Struct. For example in viewController you can load delegate:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
```

But in Struct file for example I try to the same :

```
struct sample:UITableViewDelegate
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Non-Class type 'sample' cannot conform to class protocol NSObjectProtocol
```

How can I add a delegate to Struct file?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Structs in swift can only conform protocols that not marked as class protocols with keyword `class`, like `CustomStringConvertible` protocol

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all. You can't conform to an NSObjectProtocol (father class of all protocols) if you're not a class!

Consider using a vanilla class, if it has to conform to a protocol it should not be a struct at the first place!

Comment: NSObjectProtocol isn't the top of a protocol hierarchy in Swift. There are also legitimate reasons to make structs conform to protocols in Swift--it happens frequently in the standard library, e.g.: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/int#relationships